# Deserializing xml from webclient on windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, deserialization

Hello in a Windows Phone 8 app I have run into a problem, with deserializing xml from a webclient download.. I wait on the DownloadStringCompletedEvent and then I use the folowing code.

```
private void PopularDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error connecting to the server");
        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
            XDocument loadedpopData = XDocument.Load(e.Result);

            var popdata = from query in loadedpopData.Descendants("pattern")
                          select new poppatterns
                          {
                              Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                              UserName = (string)query.Element("userName"),
                              DateCreated = (string)query.Element("dateCreated"),
                              ImageUrl = (string)query.Element("imageUrl"),
                              ApiUrl = (string)query.Element("apiUrl"),
                          };
            poplonglist.ItemsSource = popdata.ToList();
        }
    }
```

but it throws the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

If I but a local xml file in the project and then load that like this

```
XDocument loadedpopData = XDocument.Load("Resources/top.xml");
```

it loads fine so it must be something with the

```
XDocument loadedpopData = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
```

I tried looking at the e.Result and it is the correct data.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `e.Result` you have an XML string, but `XDocument.Load(string)` is for load data from file, and string argument is path to file, you should use `XDocument.Parse(e.Result)` to load `XDocument` from XML string data.

Post in MSDN about `Load`: [XDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Post in MSDN about `Parse`: [XDocument.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
//MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
            XDocument loadedpopData = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
```

to

```
//MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
            XDocument loadedpopData = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.. I took Roman as answers because he was first.. :-)

Comment: :) It does'nt matter as far as you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

quick cooking sample. and result as well, from LinqPad

code:

```
var xml = new XElement("root");

for (var i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
  xml.Add(new XElement("pattern", new XElement("title", "title" + i.ToString()),  
   new XElement("title", "title" + i.ToString()), 
   new XElement("userName", "userName" + i.ToString()), 
   new XElement("dateCreated", "dateCreated" + i.ToString()), 
   new XElement("imageUrl", "ImageUrl" + i.ToString()),
   new XElement("apiUrl", "ApiUrl" + i.ToString())));
}

var xmlString = xml.ToString();
var loadedpopData = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var popdata = from query in loadedpopData.Descendants("pattern")
                    select new {
                             Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                             UserName = (string)query.Element("userName"),
                             DateCreated = (string)query.Element("dateCreated"),
                             ImageUrl = (string)query.Element("imageUrl"),
                             ApiUrl = (string)query.Element("apiUrl"),
                        };
popdata.Dump();
```

Result:

Title  UserName  DateCreated  ImageUrl  ApiUrl 
title0 userName0 dateCreated0 ImageUrl0 ApiUrl0 
title1 userName1 dateCreated1 ImageUrl1 ApiUrl1 
title2 userName2 dateCreated2 ImageUrl2 ApiUrl2 
title3 userName3 dateCreated3 ImageUrl3 ApiUrl3 
title4 userName4 dateCreated4 ImageUrl4 ApiUrl4 
title5 userName5 dateCreated5 ImageUrl5 ApiUrl5 
title6 userName6 dateCreated6 ImageUrl6 ApiUrl6 
title7 userName7 dateCreated7 ImageUrl7 ApiUrl7 
title8 userName8 dateCreated8 ImageUrl8 ApiUrl8 
title9 userName9 dateCreated9 ImageUrl9 ApiUrl9